# Existance of product measure contradiction

Tags: measure-theory, product-space

I heard that given family of probability spaces
$(\Omega_{\alpha}, \mathcal{F}_{\alpha}, \mu_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$,
there exist product measure $\mu$ on product sigma-algebra (smallest sigma-algebra containing sets of the form $ \prod_{i \in I}E_i \times \prod_{\alpha \in A \setminus I} \Omega_\alpha $ for any finite $I \subseteq A$).
This product measure satisfies $$
\mu\left(\prod_{i \in I}E_i \times \prod_{\alpha \in A \setminus I} \Omega_{\alpha}\right) = \prod_{i\in I}\mu_i(E_i)
$$

However, I found example that seems to deny that existence.
The question is: what is wrong with it.

---

Observe that $\mu(\prod_{\alpha\in A} \Omega_\alpha) = 1$, so $\mu$ is probability measure.
This implies we have continuity from below as well as from above.

Let $A = \mathbb{N}$. Then
\begin{align}
\mu\left(\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n\right)
& = \mu\left(\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \prod_{n=1}^k E_n \times \prod_{n>k}\Omega_n\right) \\
& = \lim_{k\to\infty} \mu\left(\prod_{n=1}^k E_n \times \prod_{n>k} \Omega_n\right) \\
& = \lim_{k\to\infty} \prod_{n=1}^k \mu_n(E_n) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \mu_n(E_n).
\end{align}
Of course such infinite products are measurable, as they are countable intersections of cylinders.

Next choose any non-trivial probability space $(\Omega_0, \mathcal{F}_0, \mu_0)$ and pick $E \in \mathcal{F}_0$
such that $\mu_0(E) \in (0, 1)$. By $\mu$ denote product measure on $\Omega_0^{\mathbb N}$, where each
probability space was the same as initial one. Denote $$
E_n = \prod_{k\leq n} \Omega_0 \times \prod_{k > n} E.
$$
We have $E_n \subseteq E_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and therefore $$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(E_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k > n}\mu_0(E) = 0,
$$
but on the other hand $$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n\right) = \mu\left(\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \Omega_0\right) = 1.
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\omega_0\in\Omega_0-E$.

Then for element $\omega:=(\omega_0,\omega_0,\omega_0\dots)\in\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\Omega_0$ for *every* $n$ we have: $$\omega\notin\Omega_0\times\Omega_0\times\cdots\Omega_0\times E\times E\times\cdots=E_n$$
Showing that: $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}E_n\neq\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\Omega_0$$

Comment: yeah, I typed in wrong example, sorry for that. Gonna post second question

Comment: I found flaw in my other example as well, so I'm not gonna post it. Thank you for your time

Comment: You are very welcome.